# Which way is better, and how to pass parameters to windows.forms.timer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer, multitasking

What I want to accomplish it the following thing:

I have a lot of "checks(if/else if etc)" inside a timer, that his interval is 1000 ms,

there is a text file that getting updated and the timer read it every 1000 ms and check for some specific changes,

under 1 of those conditions if it is true the timer, i need to wait 10 sec and then read another text file and then continue with the rest of the timer code.

but in the mean time the timer keep running under those 10 sec and preform the checks every 1sec for all the other conditions and this 1 also.

what i thought to do it

if the conditions  i wanted it true i will start a new timer with 10sec interval and it will continue with the code of that specific part.

but what i have hard time to accomplish is how to pass parameters into that timer

such as

```
newTimer.Start(int "parameter", string "parameter b", list<string> parameters c")
```

etc etc

or if you got any other idea i will be glad to hear.

Comment: `async` / `await` makes this _much_ simpler.

Answer (score 0):

To pass parameters, you can always use [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx).

```
newTimer.Start(Tuple.Create(param1, param2, param3));
```

You might not need to have two timer if you do the logic correctly.

```
Timer *run every second*
    Check file

    If file has flag Then save in variable the current date + 10 seconds

    If current date > saved date Then Check the other file
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider that a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` will run on the GUI thread (the thread that run the containing form's message loop / pump), as it uses window messages (WM_TIMER) that are processed by the GUI thread. Because of that, any code that runs under any `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` in your form will execute synchronously. So, if your start a new `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` which blocks for 10 seconds, all your other timers will be blocked as well (since the message loop is blocked).

Consider using a `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer`, as they run the timer callback on a different thread. This way, your code will run pretty much as you'd want - every one second the method will be running, regardless of weather the previous call completed or is still blocking (waiting 10 seconds).